# Singly linked list exercise in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Being completely new to the world of C, I started off with the excercise of building a singly linked list of integers:

```
/*
  Single linked list test
*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct ListElement {
    int         value;
    struct ListElement  *next;
} ListElement;


void printList(ListElement *root) {
    ListElement *current;
    current = root;

    while (current->next) {
        printf("Value: %i\n", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("Value: %i\n", current->value);
}


int freeLast(ListElement *root) {
    int retval;
    retval = 1;
    ListElement *previous;
    ListElement *current;
    current = root;

    while (current->next) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current == root) {
        retval = 0;
    }

    previous->next = NULL;
    printf("Freeing %i\n", current->value);
    free(current);
    return retval;
}


void freeList(ListElement *root) {
    while(freeLast(root));
}


ListElement * createList(int size) {
    ListElement *root;
    ListElement *current;
    root = malloc(sizeof(ListElement));

    if (root != NULL) {
        root->value = 0;
        current = root;
        int i;

        for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            current->next = malloc(sizeof(ListElement));

            if (current->next != NULL) {
                current->next->value = i;
                current = current->next;
            } else {
                freeList(root);
                return NULL;
            }
        }

        return root;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}


int main() {
    ListElement *root = createList(100);
    printList(root);
    freeList(root);
}
```

While the code compiles and runs as intended I'd like to have some feedback on the coding style, program structure and possibly existing quirks with the memory handling in C, which I hope I got right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty good. Minor points:

You can return just `root` in `createList`:

```
ListElement * createList(int size) {
    ListElement *root;
    ListElement *current;
    root = malloc(sizeof(ListElement));

    if (root != NULL) {
        root->value = 0;
        current = root;
        int i;

        for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            current->next = malloc(sizeof(ListElement));

            if (current->next != NULL) {
                current->next->value = i;
                current = current->next;
            } else {
                freeList(root);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    return root;
}
```

And your `freeList` is O(n^2) complex, because you are removing from the end. Removing from the beginning would make it O(n).

Comment: Did you mean O(n^2) instead of O(!n)?

Comment: Why? To delete last you walk over `n` elements, then to delete one before last you walk `n-1` elements and so on up to first one. This gives `1*2*...*n` iterations.

Comment: 1+2+...+n, not 1*2*....*n.

Comment: Oh, silly me. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

Consider `p = malloc(sizeof *p * n);` idiom.

---

Assume `typedef struct ListElement { ...  *next; } ListElement;` exists in some other file like `ListElement.h`

You are reviewing/maintaining code in the some `.c` file and code compiles OK,

---

Is `sizeof(ListElement)` the correct size?

```
current->next = malloc(sizeof(ListElement));
```

To make sure, 1) find the definition of `current`.  OK that is `ListElement *current;`.  2) now find the definition of  `ListElement` and its member `next`.  With a good naming convention, it should be in `ListElement.h`, or it might  might exist elsewhere.  OK find that and see the member is `struct ListElement  *next;`   3) Check to insure `ListElement` is a `typedef` for `struct ListElement`.  Now done - all OK.

---

How about less work?   Is `sizeof *(current->next)` the correct size? --> Yes - of course.  No need to check the type of `current->next`.  Done.

```
current->next = malloc(sizeof *(current->next));
```

**Minor**

`createList(0)` acts like `createList(1)`.  I'd expect `createList(0)` to have no elements - empty list.

---

Using `root` as the name of the linked-list describes the inner works of the type.  Instead, the name of the linked-list should describe the list itself and abstract its inner workings.

```
#define DECK_SIZE 52
ListElement *CardDeck = createList(DECK_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a C programmer, so I have only minor comments.

`Node` instead of `ListElement` simply because it's shorter.

[EDIT: the idea in the paragraph below is not valid.  See comments.]

In `createList` it would be possible to only do one `malloc(sizeof(ListElement) * size)` and set the `next` pointers by simple arithmetic.  It would have the advantage of also keeping the memory layout compact.  But I have no idea if this would be considered good practice in C.  Looking for someone to comment on this.

Comment: I also thought of this, but then it would be impossible to free arbitrary elements.

Comment: Each element is referred from the `next` of its predecessor (which you have to setup in `createList`) and the head node is just the pointer returned by `createList`.  So freeing elements is the same as before.

Comment: you cannot free from the middle of a contiguous block of memory. it's not a question of "good practice," it is simply not how the machine works.

Comment: Thanks.  As I said I'm not a C programmer.